# Running python 3 from command line when I have python 2 & 3 both installed

Tags: python, command-line

I started writing code in python 2, but am now doing a course that runs with python 3, so I have both installed on my Windows computer. Python 2 is my default.
Is there a way to launch python 3 from the command line if python 2 is my default?
Thanks!

Comment: simply write `python3 my_code.py`, this will use python3 if properly installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using windows, add the `Python3` folder to the `PATH` variable. And then rename the `python.exe` to `python3.exe` and then you can easily use it from command line.

Also you might observe that you will be having two `IDLE` editors, so you can select the one which uses version you want then run code as you usually do.

If you have linux then you already have `python` and `python3` in the system,

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for others encountering the same problem.

You can type:
py -3

to launch python 3 if you have python 2 installed as your default.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    cd C:\Python34\
    python.exe [path_to_you_script]

example:
    cd C:\Python34\
    python.exe "C:\Python34\000\my_script.py"